# RESTful Webservice time value issues

Tags: rest, netbeans, glassfish, wadl

I have created a RESTful webservice and this webservice uses a mysql database. This was done following a howto using the Netbeans IDE.

All is working fine except for one little thing.

There is one table that is set as a 'time' type (default values 00:00:00) but for some reason when i access the wadl i get to see:

```
<time>1970-01-01T17:00:00+01:00</time>
```

I am not a very good Java programmer but i saw in the source of the webservice that Netbeans made this:

```
public void setDate(Date time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

How do i change this to just the time value? Are there standard classes that i can use?

[edit]

I am running a glassfish server where i deployed a Netbeans generated war file.

The tutorial to generate a RESTful webservice using Netbeans and mysql

(netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html#entities-and-services)

Answer (score 0):

In the database, the time value is usually just stored as a long value ignoring the date part, which results in that when it's converted to a date, the date value is the unix epoch value (i.e. 0).

So i'm not sure that this is an issue, just convert it back to a Date on the receiving end and you'll have a date with the time properly set.

EDIT: 
I suppose you have a transfer object of some sort where you define this "time" parameter? Or are you using hibernate or similar objects as the output to your rest xml generator?

If so, have you tried changing the data type from Date to Time?

Another way would be to change the type to String and in the setDate method use SimpleDateFormat to get a string on the exact form you want.

Comment: Sounds good, but i just want to have a time value in stead of a date.

Comment: which api are you using to generate the rest xml?

Comment: I am running a glassfish server where i deployed a Netbeans generated war file. So i did not have any say in how the file was generated. (http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html#entities-and-services)

Answer (score 0):

The types exposed by the RESTful web service are defined in the class `YourTableFacadeREST`. Try to modify the returned type of the corresponding method in that class.

EDITED
The problem is that the above idea will not work when the exposed object is more complex and your date is only "a part" of that object. Probably the best solution is to handle the conversion with the code reading the object.

If your goal is just to display these data (i.e. for requests of type GET) you may try with a view. I have never done Jersey RESTful web services on a view, but it should work for the GET side. Your View should display the original table with the datetime field converted to date. See here the syntax for creating a view in MySql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: Thanks for  the comment. How would i do that? Because i just dont want to show the date format when somebody requests the webservice. Just the time. (This makes it easier to create a request)